# Como conciliar boas práticas de Orientação a Objetos e frameworks ORM para getters e setters?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, orm

Em muitos dos sistemas que trabalhei ou que tive contato, a classe que representa um modelo geralmente é um POJO, o qual mapeamos seus 
atributos para colunas (para bancos relacionais) ou atributos (para alguns bancos NoSQL). Assim, em muitos dos ORMs, é mandatório termos 
os métodos acessores (getters e setters) para trazer e levar os dados para o banco de dados.
Mas as boas práticas de orientação a objetos nos dizem que não devemos expor a estrutura interna dos nossos objetos, expondo, ao invés disso
operações que alterem o estado interno dos objetos e mantenha a consistência do estado desse objeto.

Vamos dar um exemplo. Digamos que temos a classe Client. Essa classe tem um identificador, o nome do cliente e a data da última alteração. Não podemos alterar esses dados, mas queremos persisti-los. Caso queiramos modificar o nome, teremos que também alterar o id e a data de última alteração.

O ORM necessita dos métodos getters e setters, de forma que temos:

```
@Entity
public class Client {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Index
  private String name;

  private Date lastChange;

  public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public Date lastChange() {
    return this.lastChange;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public void setString(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setLastChange() {
    this.lastChange = latChange;
  }

}
```

Da maneira que está, qualquer um, além do próprio ORM, poderia alterar o ID do objeto, provocando efeitos indesejados no restante do sistema.

Ao contrário, se fôssemos alterar utilizar a classe para respeitar as regras de orientação a objetos, teríamos algo assim:

```
@Entity
public class Client {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Index
  private String name;

  private Date lastChange;

  public Client(Long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastChange = new Date();
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public void changeName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = newIdFromClient();
    this.lastChange = new Date();
  }

  private Long getNewIdFromClient() {
    return (new Random()).nextLong();
  }

}
```

Minha pergunta é:

Como conciliar essas boas práticas com as necessidades dos frameworks ORMs?

Answer (score 0):

Se não me engano no caso do @id ele ignora os métodos get/set a não ser que você coloque o @id no get, porem existe a anotação @Access que configura se você o ORM vai acessar via Field ou Property.

http://sysout.be/2011/06/30/jpa-2-the-access-annotation/

Comment: E como você faria para as outras propriedades? Funciona do mesmo jeito? E se o framework não seguir o padrão do JPA?